# How would I get the minimum and maximum comparison possibilities per step using a preference algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I am making a comparison app, and for user experience, I'd like to implement a progress bar for the user to see. Now, it is simply impossible to know exactly how many comparisons are needed to be made, so getting a range of minimum and maximum comparisons after every comparison is ideal since I can dynamically reassure the user that they are getting closer to their goal.

The algorithm I am using is a TypeScript version of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32002512/10328585) algorithm, with one added function, `calculateMinMax()`, which returns the minimum and maximum given a length. After some (an embarrassing amount) time, I figured out that the minimum comparison value is always `C(n) = Math.floor(Math.log2(n)) + C(n - 1)`, while the maximum comparison value is always `C(n) = Math.ceil(Math.log2(n)) + C(n - 1)`. Here is the code:

```
class PrefList {
    size: number
    items: { item: number, equals: number[] }[] = [{ item: 0, equals: [] }]
    current = { item: 1, try: 0, min: 0, max: 1 }
    iteration: number = 0
    estimated: { min: number, max: number } = { min: 0, max: 0 }

    constructor(n: number)
    constructor(n: Array<any>)
    constructor(n: number | Array<any>) {
        this.size = (typeof n == "number") ? n : n.length

        const [min, max] = this.calculateMinMax(this.size)
        this.estimated = {min, max}
    }

    addAnswer(pref: -1 | 0 | 1): void {
        this.iteration++
        if (pref == 0) {
            this.items[this.current.try].equals.push(this.current.item)
            this.current = { item: ++this.current.item, try: 0, min: 0, max: this.items.length }
        } else {
            if (pref == -1) this.current.max = this.current.try
            else this.current.min = this.current.try + 1
            if (this.current.min == this.current.max) {
                this.items.splice(this.current.min, 0, { item: this.current.item, equals: [] })
                this.current = { item: ++this.current.item, try: 0, min: 0, max: this.items.length }
            }
        }
    }

    getQuestion(): { a: number, b: number } {
        if (this.current.item >= this.size) return null
        this.current.try = Math.floor((this.current.min + this.current.max) / 2)
        return ({ a: this.current.item, b: this.items[this.current.try].item })
    }

    getOrder() {
        var index = []
        for (var i in this.items) {
            index.push(this.items[i].item)
            for (var j in this.items[i].equals) {
                index.push(this.items[i].equals[j])
            }
        }
        return (index)
    }

    calculateMinMax(v: number): [number, number] {
        if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]
        const val = Math.log2(v)
        const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)
        return [Math.floor(val) + rest[0], Math.ceil(val) + rest[1]]
    }
}
```

Now, this function works when initializing the class, but that is as far as it goes. I tried thinking of multiple ways to approach the update of the minimum and maximum on each step (every time a comparison is made), but I could not figure it out. I am pretty sure there is a connection between choosing the first one vs. choosing the second one since choosing the first one in every comparison will give you the minimum amount of comparisons and choosing the second one in every comparison will give you the maximum amount of comparisons, but that is all I've got. I genuinely have no idea where to go from here. Any and all help is appreciated.

---

Here is an example of comparison (slightly modified version of original test). In this given example, you are given an array of 8 fruits, and you can choose between each one. Here's the code for testing this out:

```
var array = ["orange", "apple", "pear", "banana", "kiwifruit", "grapefruit", "peach", "cherry"]

var t = new PrefList(array.length), q
while (q = t.getQuestion()) {
    console.log(t.iteration + ". " + array[q.a] + " or " + array[q.b] + "?")
    const response = prompt("")
    var answer = parseInt(response)
    console.log("→ " + [array[q.a], "whatever", array[q.b]][answer + 1])
    t.addAnswer(answer as -1 | 1)
    console.log("")
}

var index = t.getOrder()
console.log("\nLIST IN ORDER:")
for (var i in index) console.log("\t" + (parseInt(i) + 1) + ". " + array[index[i]])
```

When running the above code, you can pick the left choice by typing 1 and the right by typing -1 (with the exception of the first choice, in which case 1 corresponds to the right item and -1 to the left).

Comment: What are you comparing? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Dave I added an example code. The entire purpose of the code is, given an array (more specifically, its size), it will give you a choice between two different options and you will be tasked with picking one. Once this finishes, it will rank all items from most-liked to least-liked. Basically a 1v1 comparison that helps you rank items. You can understand this further by looking at the original topic which the code originated from: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31976519/

Comment: @Batimius so basically comparison-based sorting?

Comment: @Luatic precisely. It uses binary search / sort to achieve this, by doing a comparison in the middle of the "already-compared" array first, and splitting it down further until it finds its right place and pushing it into its proper place in the "already-compared" array, and it repeats this cycle until there is nothing left to compare. I am just wondering how I would be able to fetch the minimum and maximum amount of comparisons needed on each "cycle" (step / comparison).

Comment: Rather than a better progress bar, why not a better algorithm?

Comment: https://github.com/decidedlyso/merge-insertion-sort/blob/master/README.md is guaranteed to minimize comparisons up to 22 element lists, and is believed optimal up to 46. With work, you can base your progress bar on the maximum number of comparisons left.

Comment: @btilly what kind of algorithm do you have in mind? This one seems very solid to me considering it doesn't do many comparisons, plus it has the upside of allowing me to run "the next step" whenever I want, which is vital for an application where user input is being taken into account.

Comment: The property of running the next step whenever you want can be done by promisifying the whole algorithm. Granted, that takes a bunch of work. But it is a property you get from being able to write async code, and not a property of the algorithm.

Comment: @btilly I'll check it out. A merge sort was actually the first algorithm I thought about implementing, but after some small difficulties, I switched over to the binary sort one. The one you sent seems interesting, so I'll definitely check it out, but I am still interested in how I would be able to achieve what I want with the binary sort algorithm.

Comment: That one is going to be more complicated to implement than merge sort. If merge sort was a problem, then you need practice with async code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. In order to find the minimum and maximum comparisons at the current step, you must store the comparisons made in the previous steps and use them when calculating the minimum and maximum.

### Explanation

To understand this better, we can break down the minimum and maximum function:

```
function calculateMinMax(v: number): [number, number] {

    // Return [0, 0] since log2(1) = 0
    if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]

    // Get the log2 of the current number
    const val = Math.log2(v)

    // Recursive call (can be ignored for now)
    const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)

    // Get the minimum amount of comparisons for this number
    const minimum = Math.floor(val)

    // Get the maximum amount of comparisons for this number
    const maximum = Math.ceil(val)

    // Return the sum of the minimum and the rest (from recursive call), and the sum of the maximum and the rest (from recursive call)
    return [
        minimum + rest[0],
        maximum + rest[1]
    ]
}
```

Now, the reason our minimum and maximum have different values is because one is rounding down while the other is rounding up. That means that a certain number could either have `x` or `x + 1` amount of comparisons before moving to the next one (unless it is a squared product of 2, in which case, `log2(n)` is a whole number and therefore only `x`). The variation in the two values will always come from the difference in comparisons of each number. This is the one and only variable that fluctuates our possibilities and range.

So, what can we do to counter it? Simple, use the realistic numbers. When calculating the minimum and maximum, we use theoretical numbers.

Let us assume that we are running this code on an array of 16 elements, and all our answers will be `1` (so `a > b`, `b > c`, and so on). Say that we are comparing the 9th element. If do our calculations, we will see that `log2(9) = 3.1699250014`, which means that our minimum comparisons for the 9th element is 3 and the maximum is 4. That is good and dandy, but what if we are on the 12th element? Well, since we are always choosing `1` as our answer, we know that the 9th element was compared a total of 3 times before moving onto the next. Having this information in mind, we can get rid of the min / max values and simply replace them with the existing ones since we no longer need to rely on theory, we already got our answer.

To do this, simply keep track of how many comparisons each element took before moving onto the next. How you do this is up to you, but for the sake of the explanation, I'll create an imaginary function called `getTotalComparisons(n)` which will either return the total comparisons for number `n` or `null`. Now, we could get rid of the minimum and maximum, but for the sake of simplicity, I'll simply be replacing the `val` value to our total comparisons since a whole number rounded up or down will always have the same number. Here is how this would look like:

```
function calculateMinMax(v: number): [number, number] {

    // Return [0, 0] since log2(1) = 0
    if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]

    // Get the total comparisons of the current number, if any
    const totalComparisons = this.getTotalComparisons(v)

    // If `totalComparison` is not null, set `val` to `totalComparison`, else set `val` to log2 of the current number
    const val = (totalComparisons) ? totalComparisons : Math.log2(v)

    // Recursive call (can be ignored for now)
    const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)

    // Get the minimum amount of comparisons for this number
    const minimum = Math.floor(val)

    // Get the maximum amount of comparisons for this number
    const maximum = Math.ceil(val)

    // Return the sum of the minimum and the rest (from recursive call), and the sum of the maximum and the rest (from recursive call)
    return [
        minimum + rest[0],
        maximum + rest[1]
    ]
}
```

And that is all. This should now return the minimum and maximum amount of comparisons based on the current step. You can run this function after (or before) every answer to know how many questions are possibly left.

### Solution

Below is the modified code, with the modification of the `calculateMinMax` class to allow for per-step results:

```
class PrefList {
    size: number
    items: { item: number}[] = [{ item: 0 }]
    current = { item: 1, try: 0, min: 0, max: 1 }
    iteration: number = 0
    comparisonValues: {[key: number]: number} = {}

    constructor(n: number)
    constructor(n: Array<any>)
    constructor(n: number | Array<any>) {
        this.size = (typeof n == "number") ? n : n.length
    }

    addAnswer(pref: -1 | 1): void {
        this.iteration++
        if (!this.comparisonValues[this.current.item]) this.comparisonValues[this.current.item] = 0
        this.comparisonValues[this.current.item]++
        
        if (pref == -1) this.current.max = this.current.try
        else this.current.min = this.current.try + 1

        if (this.current.min == this.current.max) {
            this.items.splice(this.current.min, 0, { item: this.current.item})
            this.current = { item: ++this.current.item, try: 0, min: 0, max: this.items.length }
        }
    }

    getQuestion(): { a: number, b: number } {
        if (this.current.item >= this.size) return null
        this.current.try = Math.floor((this.current.min + this.current.max) / 2)
        return ({ a: this.current.item, b: this.items[this.current.try].item })
    }

    getOrder() {
        var index = []
        for (var i in this.items) {
            index.push(this.items[i].item)
        }
        return (index)
    }

    calculateMinMax(v: number = this.size) {
        if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]

        const comparisons = this.comparisonValues[v - 1]
        const val = (comparisons && this.current.item != v - 1) ? this.comparisonValues[v - 1] : Math.log2(v)
        const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)

        return [Math.floor(val) + rest[0], Math.ceil(val) + rest[1]]
    }
}
```