# Getting accurate minimum and maximum comparisons using a binary-insertion sorting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting, binary-search

About a week ago, I asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77284249/) question about getting the minimum and maximum comparisons on every comparison using a binary-sorting algorithm. I ended up figuring it out, and a lengthy explanation can be found at the answer of that post. In short, the following code accomplishes this task:

```js
calculateMinMax(v: number = this.size) {
        if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]

        const comparisons = this.comparisonValues[v - 1]
        const val = (comparisons && this.current.item != v - 1) ? this.comparisonValues[v - 1] : Math.log2(v)
        const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)

        return [Math.floor(val) + rest[0], Math.ceil(val) + rest[1]]
    }
```

Now, this code works great, but it has a small problem. Although it decreases the max and increases the minimum accurately, it is not really 100% accurate. For instance, using an array of 5 strings (a - e) and supplying all answers with -1 (so inverting the array), it gives the following output:

[image]

As you can see, on question 8 (7 comparisons in), it still says that there are a minimum of 7 comparisons, which is simply impossible considering that we are already on the 7th. The true answer should be `[8, 8]`.

Another similar case happens with the max. Here is the output:

[image]
[image]

Regardless of if I put -1 or 1 as my answer, the algorithm will finish at question 6 (so once you submit it, a total of 6 comparison will have been made), meaning that it will never reach 7 comparisons, no matter what choice you pick.

That said, although I could create a hacky way for solving the min issue (check if the comparisons are the same as the minimum, and if they are, increase the minimum by 1), but that's the equivalent of putting a band-aid on a bullet hole. I'd love to figure out why this happens and any possible fixes for it. Here is the entire class in case you need it:

```js
class PrefList {
    size: number
    items: { item: number}[] = [{ item: 0 }]
    current = { item: 1, try: 0, min: 0, max: 1 }
    iteration: number = 0
    comparisonValues: {[key: number]: number} = {}

    constructor(n: number)
    constructor(n: Array<any>)
    constructor(n: number | Array<any>) {
        this.size = (typeof n == "number") ? n : n.length
    }

    addAnswer(pref: -1 | 1): void {
        this.iteration++
        if (!this.comparisonValues[this.current.item]) this.comparisonValues[this.current.item] = 0
        this.comparisonValues[this.current.item]++
        
        if (pref == -1) this.current.max = this.current.try
        else this.current.min = this.current.try + 1

        if (this.current.min == this.current.max) {
            this.items.splice(this.current.min, 0, { item: this.current.item})
            this.current = { item: ++this.current.item, try: 0, min: 0, max: this.items.length }
        }
    }

    getQuestion(): { a: number, b: number } {
        if (this.current.item >= this.size) return null
        this.current.try = Math.floor((this.current.min + this.current.max) / 2)
        return ({ a: this.current.item, b: this.items[this.current.try].item })
    }

    getOrder() {
        var index = []
        for (var i in this.items) {
            index.push(this.items[i].item)
        }
        return (index)
    }

    calculateMinMax(v: number = this.size) {
        if (v <= 1) return [0, 0]

        const comparisons = this.comparisonValues[v - 1]
        const val = (comparisons && this.current.item != v - 1) ? this.comparisonValues[v - 1] : Math.log2(v)
        const rest = this.calculateMinMax(v - 1)

        return [Math.floor(val) + rest[0], Math.ceil(val) + rest[1]]
    }
}
```